# Torch CUDA memory not releasing with torch.empty.cache()

Tags: python, django

I want to clean up GPU memory using `deallocate_memory`.

It works with the `exit` function but when I call `deallocate_memory`, the memory is not released.

My code:

```
class ChatbotConfig(AppConfig):
   
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'chatbot'
    session_queue = Queue(maxsize=10)
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    session_data = {}
    models_initialized = False  # Flag to track if models have been initialized
    initialized_retriever = None
    initialized_prompt_node = None
    initialized_document_store = None
    tokenizer = None
    model = None
    session_lock = threading.Lock()  # Lock for session management
    initialization_lock = threading.Lock()

    processing_complete_event = threading.Event()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.models_initialized = False

    def ready(self):
        # self.deallocate_gpu_memory()
        # Register resource cleanup for application exit
        atexit.register(self.cleanup_resources)

        # create a thread for each session
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.process_queue)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

        # Create a separate thread to handle session cleanup
        cleanup_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.session_cleanup)
        cleanup_thread.daemon = True  # The thread will exit when the main program exits
        cleanup_thread.start()

    def session_cleanup(self):
        while True:
            current_time = timezone.now()
            session_timeout = settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE

            # Assuming you have a session queue called 'ChatbotConfig.session_queue'
            session_data = ChatbotConfig.session_data

            # Create a dictionary to store session data
            to_remove = []

            for session_id, data in session_data.items():
                last_activity_str = data.get('last_activity')

                if session_id and last_activity_str:
                    last_activity = datetime.fromisoformat(last_activity_str)
                    inactivity_duration = (
                        current_time - last_activity).total_seconds()

                    if inactivity_duration > session_timeout:
                        print(f'Session {session_id} is timing out')
                        # User is inactive, release GPU memory
                        self.deallocate_gpu_memory()
                        to_remove.append(session_id)


            # Remove timed-out sessions outside the loop
            for session_id in to_remove:
                del self.session_data[session_id]

            # Sleep for a period before checking sessions again (adjust as needed)
            time.sleep(20)

    def ready(self):
            # self.deallocate_gpu_memory()
            # Register resource cleanup for application exit
            atexit.register(self.cleanup_resources)def cleanup_resources(self):
            self.deallocate_gpu_memory()
    
    def deallocate_gpu_memory(self):
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            device = torch.device('cuda:0')

            # Allocate a small amount of GPU memory
            dummy_tensor = torch.tensor([0.0], device=device)

            # Ensure all GPU operations are completed
            torch.cuda.synchronize()

            # Delete the dummy tensor
            del dummy_tensor

            # Empty the cache to release memory
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()

            print('GPU memory released')

... rest of the code
```

any suggestion how to fix it? The model I'm using is llama2-7B